# Where can I download tagged word dictionary and rule?

Tags: cpu-word, nlp, tagging

I am learning to tag part of speech by applying transformational rules. The first step is to tag the possible POS to each word in a text by using a dictionary like:

```
communicative JJ
communicator NN
communicators NNS
communion NN
communique NN
communiques NNS
communism NN
```

The second step is to apply transformational rules to change tags. I have only a very small dictionary containing the above word/tag pairs. Where can I find a large one and where can I find transformational rules? It is said tagging based on transformation may have a lot of rules. Where can I find the rules?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd obtain the possibilities from a corpus, such as those available in [NLTK](http://nltk.org). That would also give you frequencies from which to estimate probabilities, if you want to do machine-learned tagging ([Brill](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Brill_tagger)-style).

The rules must be handcrafted, after which the machine learner can find out when to apply which ones. See, e.g., [Brill's PhD thesis](http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/acl/H/H92/H92-1022.pdf) for English rules.